# Equality between matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A,B$ be $n$-th dimensional complex Hermitian matrices, and suppose that $e^{-iA} = e^{-iB}$. Does this necessarily imply that $A = B$?

If we expand the expression, then
then
$$
I + iA - \frac{A^2}{2} - i\frac{A^3}{3!}+\ldots = I + iB - \frac{B^2}{2} -i\frac{B^3}{3!}+\ldots
$$
but how can this imply $A = B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $-iA$ and $-iB$ are skew-Hermitian, and the exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak{u}(n)\rightarrow U(n)$ is not injective in this case - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective).

Comment: What are $u(n)$ and $U(n)$?

Comment: $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is the space of skew-Hermitian matrices of size $n$, and $U(n)$ the unitary group.