# When is the exponential map of a Lie group a diffeomorphism?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

A necessary condition for the exponential map $\mathfrak{g}\to G$ to be a diffeomorphism is that $G$ is contractible. Is this also sufficient? I can't think of a proof or any counterexamples.

Comment: @Jap88: the circle isn't contractible.

Comment: Completely answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective In particular it is not sufficient.